# CVS remove a project from a branch

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, repository, cvs, tortoisecvs

I created a new branch from HEAD and tried adding 3 projects to it. By mistake i added 2 additional projects to it which were actually not required in the branch.

To avoid confusion to future users of the branch/head,  i want to remove those 2 projects from the branch and still keep them in HEAD so that anybody in future will only see those 2 projects in the HEAD.

i do not have write permissions on the CVS physical Server, is there any way to do from the cvs plugin inside eclipse?

Pls guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this from the Eclipse CVS plugin.  Rather, I think you will need to do this from the command line.

First, check out the entire branch from CVS.  `cd` to the directory just above the projects you want to delete.  Then use this command:

```
cvs remove -R proj1 proj2 ...
```